# Конкатенация строк в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы `story` и `chapter`, из которых я делаю запрос

```
select distinct story.id, story.theme, chapter.text
from story join chapter on story.id=chapter.story_id
where completion_time is not null
```

И на выходе получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы в одной строке выводились тексты с одинаковыми id через разделитель. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT('Paris', ',', 'France') AS Location;

Comment: @Yaroslav нужно взять `text`, где id одинаковый, простой concat не подойдет

Comment: [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Akina спасибо, получилось